# I can't update my contacts

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I read some tutorials on MEAN Stack and I'm currently working on one which is almost complete, until I tried my update function. I keep on receiving a 400 message and when i look at the chrome dev tools and under the network tab I read the response which is "_id" is not allowed.

here is the update function

```
$scope.update = () => {
    console.log($scope.contact._id);
    $http.put('/api/contacts/updatecontact/' + $scope.contact._id, $scope.contact)
    .then(function(data) {
        alert('Data was updated Successfully');
        refresh();
    });
  };
```

here is the api.

```
app.put('/api/contacts/updatecontact/:id', (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
console.log(req.body.name);
 // validation
 const { error } = validateInput(req.body);
 if (error){
     return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
 }
const updatedContact = Contact.where({ _id: id });
updatedContact.update({
    $set: { name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email
    }
}, (err, contact) => {
    if(err){
        console.log('error occured');
    }

    res.json(contact);
    console.log('contact successfully updated');
});
console.log(updatedContact);
```

});

hope i can get some help with this.

Comment: how does your api look like

Comment: wait i'll just edit this and add the api

Comment: you are sending contact and accessing name in api

Comment: can u explain further?

Comment: {"_id":"5b237c3319d496019c24f512","name":"Ron Mark","email":"ronmarkdoe@email.com","__v":0}
this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the node.api is validating the json object that you are passing. Make sure the properties you sent form the client.

Make sure you are not validating or remove the validation on the node.